# How to check a child_process callback for truthiness?

Tags: node.js, callback, child-process

I want to return a boolean from the method `exec` of `child_process`:

```
   myFunction = () => {
        exec(`some command`, (err, stdout) => {
        if (err) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (stdout.toString().toLowerCase().includes(`success`)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
       }).stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
   },

   if (myFunction()) {
       console.log('all good')
   }
```

As I understood, `myFunction` is not an async so there is no use for an await. Is there a different solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm..  I think you'll find that `exec` itself is async. Putting it inside myFunction doesn't magically stop it being async. When you call `myFunction()` it kicks off the`exec` then immediately returns null because there is no `return` in `myFunction`. Later, when the `some command` has finished, the callback is run, but it does not return anything to the original thread.

Comment: You could try using execSync instead, that might help.